# Referencing javadoc of project dependency

Tags: gradle, javadoc

I have couple projects where project A is a dependency of project B. So, in project B's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':A')
}
```

Project B's javadoc references a lot of classes that are in project A, including inheriting javadoc from abstract classes and interfaces. However, they're all showing up as fully qualified class names with no links to project A's javadoc. Understandable, since I didn't hook them up in any fashion.

Is it possible to have the javadoc task reference the source of another project? I'm OK with project A's classes being in project B's javadoc. The javadoc task has a `source` property which I could set to both project B and A's source set, I'm just unsure how to reference project A's source or if there's a better way of doing this.

Side note: To link to JDK/Guava/etc. Javadoc, I'm setting `javadoc.options.links`. Since I'm not hosting project A's javadoc externally, I don't think this applies here, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on whether you want to publish these javadocs separately or together. The latter is often the case and you can solve it with just one `Javadoc` task that will process all the sources in one run and then it knows how to cross-link them (cf. how it is done for Gradle codebase - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/docs.gradle#L312). If you want to publish them separately on the same site you can try to build them in right order and link using relative path.